# How to get a node with index n in Lemon Graph Library?

Tags: c++, lemon-graph-library

When I build a graph `g` with this code:

```
ListDigraph g;

for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
  g.addNode();
```

its nodes will have indexes {0..6}, which I tested by calling `g.id()` on them. How can I get a node by using its index? For example, I would like to add an arc to `g` by calling:

```
g.addArc(<node n>, <node m>);
```

Comment: Assuming lemon doesn't have such function and assuming the id doesn't change, maybe you can maintain your own vector to which you can push new nodes?

Comment: @user2079303 Yes, this is an option, but I would prefer using Lemon API.

Comment: In that case you can use the node iterator and check the nodes linearly until you find the correct id.

Comment: @user2079303 _check the nodes linearly until you find the correct id_  - that would be hugely inefficient.

Comment: That's the fastest way to search a linked list which is what `ListDigraph` uses internally (a vector of lists according to the documentation).

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with `nodeFromId` member function, see [Graph Class Reference](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/1.2.3/a00152.html):

```
g.addArc(g.nodeFromId(n), g.nodeFromId(m));
```